# PhoneNumberUtil libphonenumber dialing international numbers without prefix

Tags: c#, libphonenumber

using googles PhoneNumberUtil, the c# ported version I am trying to dial a numbers like below

441392200200 (that have the plus(+) prefix missing)

it has obviously the missing plus char at the beginning, i.e. it should be +441392200200

Is there any function in this library that I overlooked to automatically correct the number so it actually matches a valid number, I could simply add the plus char but its a little complicated given the dialing rules globally, I wouldnt know at what length the number should be to add the plus char

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().format(phoneNo, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/